# vuejs - dynamic input 'types'

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I would like to be able to dynamically change the `type` of an input field between `text` and `password`. I tried doing the following:

```
<input :type="dynamicInputType">

data() {
    return {
        dynamicInputType: 'password'
    }
}
```

But apparently this doesn't work; vuejs displays the error: `v-model does not support dynamic input types. Use v-if branches instead.`

It's not clear to me how I can fix this with v-if.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of thing is what's being suggested.

```
<input v-if="'text' === dynamicInputType" type="text">
<input v-else type="password">
```